# Plot vertical lines separately

Tags: r, line, distribution, density-plot

I created a density plot for my variable. I then used facet_wrap to show the distribution for each male and female participants. I wanted to plot the mean for each male and female in their plot separately, but it shows me both means in both density plot. How can I get only the "male-mean" in the male plot and the "female-mean" in the female plot?
I used the following code

```
plot3 + geom_density() + facet_wrap(~gender) +
geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 2.9), color = "red") + 
geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 3.1), color = "red")
```

Answer (score 1):

summarise new dataset, then mapping `aes`.

```
library(tidyverse)
d2 <- iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarise(mm = mean(Sepal.Length))
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_vline(data = d2, aes(xintercept = mm)) +
  facet_wrap(~Species)
```

[image]